# How to create an Org Policy Constraint with conditions? - GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am working on a small project in python, with which I could create the org policy gcp.disableSerialPortAccess as "Not Enforced" Org Policy with the condition of "tagValues/776487819778".

I can feel it that is something simple, but i do not understand how to create the request...

I tried using this request https://github.com/googleapis/python-org-policy/blob/main/samples/generated_samples/orgpolicy_v2_generated_org_policy_create_policy_sync.py , but i do not know how to construct it.

This is how i try to end up:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/tags-organization-policy#boolean_policy_example

Spec : Rule Enforce with Condition as "tagValues/776487819778"

Can someone please help?

```
from google.cloud import orgpolicy_v2
from google.cloud.orgpolicy_v2 import types

Exp=(
    "expression" : "tagValues/776487819778",
    "title" : "this is the title",
    "description" : "this is a description",
    )


def build_policy():
    
    
    
    
    
    rule = types.PolicySpec.PolicyRule()
    rule.enforce = False
    rule.condition = (Exp)
    


    print(types.PolicySpec.PolicyRule)
    
    spec = types.PolicySpec()
    spec.rules.append(rule)
    

    policy = types.Policy(
        name="projects/project-id/policies/gcp.disableSerialPortAccess",
        spec = spec
        )

    return policy


def sample_update_policy():
    # Create a client   
    client = orgpolicy_v2.OrgPolicyClient()

    policy = build_policy()

    # Debug - view created policy
    print(policy)

    # Initialize request argument(s)
    request = orgpolicy_v2.UpdatePolicyRequest(
        policy=policy,
    )

    # Make the request
    response = client.update_policy(request=request)
    
    # Handle the response
    print(response)

sample_update_policy()
```

Comment: The answer from @ernestoc is also correct and provides useful links to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exp is a dictionary (Key/Value).

To duplicate the example in your [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/tags-organization-policy#boolean_policy_example) use the following code:

```
def build_policy():
    Exp = {
        "expression" : "resource.matchTagId('org-id-from-gcp/disableSerialAccess', 'yes')",
        "title" : "this is the title",
        "description" : "this is a description",
    }

    rule1 = types.PolicySpec.PolicyRule()
    rule1.enforce = True
    rule1.condition = Exp

    rule2 = types.PolicySpec.PolicyRule()
    rule2.enforce = False

    spec = types.PolicySpec()

    spec.rules.append(rule1)
    spec.rules.append(rule2)

    policy = types.Policy(
        name="projects/project-id-from-gcp/policies/gcp.disableSerialPortAccess",
        spec = spec
    )

    return policy
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expression field in `Exp` needs to use the IAM attribute `resource.matchTagId(tagKey, tagValues)` to be a valid expression. From the [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#resource-tags) documentation:

> Checks whether the resource for the request has a tag with the specified key and value.

Something else to note is that the `Exp` dictionary has to be using curly braces instead of parentheses in case it's not compiling (or could be a typo):

```python
#Using the IAM attribute
Exp = {
    "expression" : "resource.matchTagId('tagKeys/1234', 'tagValues/776487819778')",
    "title" : "this is the title",
    "description" : "this is a description",
}
```

[This](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy) another page is also useful if you need further samples and details about the fields inside a `Policy` type (including the CEL expression syntax).

Comment: I did not mean to step on your answer. When I started writing my answer, your answer was not there yet.